# Are there any temples in which the main deity is Sita?

Tags: temple, sita, deity

Are there any temples in which the main deity is Sita? Or is she always worshiped as Rama's spouse?

Comment: https://www.bhaskar.com/religion/dharam/karila-mela-temple-in-ashoknagar-madhya-pradesh-01519161.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seetha_Amman_Temple

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sita_temples

Answer (score 3):

Temples of Devi Sita are as follows:

Sita Amman Temple Sri Lanka

[image]

Janaki Mandir Nepal

[image]

Seetha Devi Temple in Wayanad district, Kerala

[image]

Sita Mai Temple

[image]

Sita Samahit Temple in Bijnor district, Uttar Pradesh

[image]

Punaura Dham Sita Kund in Sitamarhi District, Bihar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sita madhi temple of Mithila in Bihar
And
Janki mandir of Nepal